# C++ hash table for storing objects of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, hashtable

I've seen plenty of hash table implementation for string or int value. But, i need help on how to store objects as a value in a hash table. I created a Book class and need to store its instances into a hash table. How do i do that ?
Below is my hash table implementation using separate chaining to avoid collision.

...

```
#ifndef HASH_H_
#define HASH_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class hashtable{
  private:
    static const int tablesize = 10;

    struct book{
        string name;
        string author;
        book* next;
    };

book* HashTable[tablesize];



public:
    hashtable();
    int Hash(string key);
    void Add(string key, string author);
    int num(int index);
    void PrintTable();
    void PrintItems(int index);
};

#endif


hashtable::hashtable(){
  for(int i=0; i<tablesize; i++){
    HashTable[i] = new book;
    HashTable[i]->name = "empty";
    HashTable[i]->author = "empty";
    HashTable[i]->next = NULL;
  }
}

void hashtable::Add(string name, string author){
  int index = Hash(name);
  if (HashTable[index]->name == "empty"){
    HashTable[index]->name = name;
    HashTable[index]->author = author;
  }else{
    book* Ptr = HashTable[index];
    book* n = new book;
    n->name = name;
    n->author = author;
    n->next = NULL;
    while (Ptr->next != NULL){
      Ptr = Ptr->next;
    }
    Ptr->next = n;
  }
}
...
```

Comment: What is your undertanding of what a hash table is, and what it does? If your understanding is correct, you would already know everything that you need to know in order to create a hash table of your objects. Therefore, your real question is really about something you don't understand about what hash tables are, and how they work.

Comment: I know how they work in theory and im trying to put it in practice. Im sorry i have no idea about how to create a hash table of objects. That's why i posted a question here in hope of getting help.

Comment: Hashing is an abstract concept that works on anything. Integers. Strings. Or classes. There is no difference, in concept, of creating a hash table of objects, or a hash table of integers, or strings. It is not clear what your question is. What is it ***specifically*** you don't understand about how to hash objects? What is your understanding of "how they work in theory", and what is your question about applying the theory of hashing to your objects?

Comment: You seem to have two separate and somewhat complicated tasks. 1) Create a hashing algorithm for `Book`. 2). Create a container `class` that uses hashes for fast lookup. You could solve one at a time. I suggest starting with the hashing algorithm since `std::hash<std::string>` already exists and combining two hashes can be done using `boost::hash_combine` or similar.

Comment: this struct of mine contains the key value pair. Replacing the "string author" with "Book Bookobj" and modifying data type to Book gives conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map, but you'll need something to use as the hash. Book name perhaps?

```
std::map<std::string, Book> bookMap;
```

You could then access books with:

```
bookMap["Flowers for Algernon"]
```

Insertions are a little tricky.

```
ptr = bookMap( pair<string, Book>("The Old Man of the Sea", myBook) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is there a way to do so without using a STL?